# how to add values in particular columns and print in a separate file using python?

Tags: python, text-files

I have a file with 5 columns, say:

> input file:
>   1 1 1 1 1
>   1 1 1 0 1
>   1 0 0 1 1

I want the output file with the 1st column printed as such, the 2nd,3rd and 4th column values should be added together and the fifth to be printed as such again.

> output file:
>   1 3 1
>   1 2 1
>   1 1 1

Comment: Have you tried to do this for yourself at all?

Comment: I used a looping statement and tried line.split()[0] for printing the 1st column and used the same line.split()[4] for printing the last column. I dont know to add the middle columns

Comment: @ZeissIkon : I dont know if it will be apt to use the append function.

Comment: It's always helpful to post any code you've got (sounds like you have some). If not it can come across as though you're asking people to do something for you instead of to answer a question. It also gives everybody some common ground to talk about the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try like this:

```
f = open('input_file')
for x in f:
    x = x.split()
    print("{} {} {}".format(x[0],(sum(map(int,x[1:4]))),x[4]))
f.close()
```

output:

```
1 3 1
1 2 1
1 1 1
```

write to file:

```
f = open('input_file')
f1 = open('output_file')
for x in f:
    x = x.split()
    f1.write("{} {} {}".format(x[0],(sum(map(int,x[1:4]))),x[4])))
f.close()
f1.close()
```

Comment: this code gives an error for "f1.write("{} {} {}".format(x[0],(sum(map(int,x[1:3])),x[4])))" line. It says tuple index out of range.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are having a bit of trouble getting the data in a workable format. I would suggest reading the python documentation:https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html for input and output of files and https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html for the very useful csv module. I've put together a code snippet that is easy to understand and gets your data into one workable array. you can easily edit this to have the data in a structure you find more preferable.

```
import csv
data = []
with open('data.txt') as csvfile:
    content = csv.reader(csvfile , delimiter=' ')
    for row in content:
        data += row

for i in range(len(data)):
    data[i] = int(data[i])


print data
>>> [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]
```

From here you should be able to easily manipulate the data to do what you want. I would suggest reading the documentation on writing to files, then coming back, show us your code and see where you went wrong if you run into trouble.

Comment: I dont want the data to be processed like an array, I want to process it row wise.

Comment: @ In that case I may have to look into a 2d array processing, which I dont wish to.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Input:

```
1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 0 1
1 0 0 1 1
```

Program:

```
fp1=open("file.txt","r")
for i in fp1.readlines():
    line = i[:-1].split(' ')
    line = map(int,line)        
    x = reduce(lambda x, y: x+y ,line[1:-1])
    print line[0],x,line[4]
```

Output:

```
1 3 1
1 2 1
1 1 1
```

Comment: the map function gives an error, stating "invalid literal for int() with base 10: '' "